# PHP closing tag showing, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, html

I'm putting in my php to echo out just a basic html hello world paragraph and it seems to work okay except for the fact every time I'm getting the ending ;?> tag showing in my website.

My code looks like the below:

```
   <?php
   echo "<p>Hello World.</p>";
   ?>
```

Frankly this happens with any php I have inserted into my html file but i figure I would just show a simple example here. Any reason why this would happen? The

update with exapmple:

Hello World.

";
    ?>
Thanks.

Comment: When you right click and view source, do you see your php code?

Comment: Please post a larger code snippet that shows the problem. The code you posted above would definitely cause the ending php tag to be output as-is.

Comment: Are you sure file extension is **.php**

Comment: When I first created this thread I accidentally forgot my 8 spaces at the beginning of each line of code which also created the issue I'm talking about. See the original post again with updated content.

RE to Nitin. The problem is, I would rather not use PHP file extension and want to use HTML which I thought was possible

Comment: First try renaming your .html to .php , Does it work ??????

Comment: And you're not seeing `<?php` showing up?

Comment: Yeah, if your server is not set up to parse .html files for php, then you cannot name your files with .html and expect them to get parsed.

Comment: Thanks Ian... That's most likely my issue. I'll have to figure out how to configure the server to do so

Comment: @James , I already told you before in my answer :) you forgot to look at it I guess. You can see `edited 20 mins ago`

Comment: I think I missed the Edit part. Thanks again. overlooked it i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP tags will work in file with .php extension only. If you provide .html file to the server  , it will treat it as simple html as if it has NO server side content,it will just send the file as it is to browser without processing it.So in short in .HTML file , tags are not getting processed by server.

**Edit** : you can configure your webserver to also thread *.html as php, but it seems you haven't. First try renaming your .html to .php

Comment: No, you can configure your webserver to also thread *.html as php!

Comment: @Rizier123 , but OP hasnt.

Comment: Who said that he even has a webserver with php?

Comment: How could you possibly even *know* @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com?

Comment: I'm using a web hosting server which is well known and has php on it

Comment: @James Hello Sir, I am asking Do you have webserver config, that treats .html files  as .php files?

Comment: Ah... that's probably my problem. Thanks, I'll now have to find out how to configure the server to do so.

Comment: @Rizier123 , why am i getting downvote ? I explained him properly in new Edit too.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com How should I know this?

Comment: Your not getting the downvote... I am lol. Noob question

Answer (score 1):

You are naming your php files as .html and your server is not configured to parse .html files for PHP code.

If you're using the Apache web server, you can add this configuration by adding a `.htaccess` file to the web root of your project directory, containing this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: Thanks Ian and jQuery.PHP.Magento.com going to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score -5):

You have to escape the php by \ 
Or you can echo separately:

```
<?php
echo "<html>"; 
echo "<body>";
echo "<p>Hello World.</p>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>"
?>
```

Comment: It does not matter even there are spaces before echo OR <?php tag , it still works.

Comment: true, but if I run it like that in coda (on Mac OSx) I don't get the extra ; ?>

Comment: Thats nice, question is already has accepted answer, thanks.